# rosmatlab- publisher

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using rosmatlab package for making a bridge between Matlab and Ros. I want to publish some interger data. But I couldnot find any proper Documentation for it.
I am having problem with the syntax of
`ros.publisher.publish();`
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/108381/rosmatlab--publisher/) by [Ram99](https://answers.ros.org/users/9696/ram99/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-12-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
you should follow the documentation from mathworks to launch a roscore and create a node in matlab.
Then you can add a publisher to your node by using, in matlab :

```
publisher = rosmatlab.publisher('your_topic_name', 'std _ msgs/Int32', your_node);
```

---

Originally posted by [NStaub](https://answers.ros.org/users/13056/nstaub/) with karma: 16 on 2014-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0